# Android (Java) convert a hh:mm:ss time String into a number representation

Tags: java, android, string

The problem i am having is that i have a time string which is represented in terms of "hh:mm:ss" and the server only accepts float numerical for the time (this is beyond my control).

Currently i am removing all ':' characters from the String, so for example "11:23:23" becomes "112323".

With the "new" String i can then convert it to a number representation for example:

int x = Integer.parseInt("112323);

This will produce the integer value 112323.

Now, my problem is because it is a timer, sometimes the time represented in the String is quite low. If i had the time string "00:00:01" and removed the ':' characters it would produce the integer value 1.

This is because if am not mistaken, the integer value 000001 will be "trimmed" as the 0's do not change the value of the integer so the value 1 is returned.

Is there a way to specify that i want to display the full 6 digits regardless of the fact they maybe "insignificant" in terms of the number value?

my code:

```
String timeTrimmed = pois.get(i).getTimeStamp().replaceAll(":","");
                int result = Integer.parseInt(timeTrimmed);
```

is it possible to do something like this:

```
String timeTrimmed = pois.get(i).getTimeStamp().replaceAll(":","");
                int result = Integer.parseInt(######,timeTrimmed);
```

with the # representing the fact i want the integer to keep all the digits?

I hope you understand what i mean,

Cheers,
Chris.

Comment: The only way to do that would be to keep the number representation in a `String` object. An `Integer` object will always trim the zeros.

Comment: Are you sure you don't need the time in milliseconds rather than that pseudo-decimal representation?

Comment: why not split the sting on ":" now you'd have an array with the strings representing the hours, the minutes and the seconds. Parse all of them to ints. multiply the minutes by 60 and the hours by 3600. Sum the three parts and you have the time in seconds (integer).

Comment: @Manitoba it doent have to be an Integer it can be Double/Float or anything else that is classed as a number representation

Comment: What value is this "float numerical" actually meant to be? If it's mean to be something like "seconds since the Unix epoch" you can't just use an arbitrary value.

Comment: @chris: numbers CAN'T have leading zeroes. That's all.

Comment: @Tobor cheers, i think ill use your suggestion if you want to post an answer im happy to accept. ill just tell the sever people to decode it back to hh:mm:ss on their end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not split the sting on ":"?
Now you'd have an array with the strings representing the hours, the minutes and the seconds.
Parse all of them to ints.
Multiply the minutes by 60 and the hours by 3600.
Sum the three parts and you have the time in seconds (integer).

On the other side of the net, decoding seconds to an "hh:mm:ss" formatted string would be a trivial task.